# How to show all date from a certain Month by horizontally?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have database table in postgreSQL name as "time" like:

| Name | Date1 | AttendHour1 | Date2 | AttendHour2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zakir1 | 2018-10-01 | 8.00 | 2018-10-02 | 8.00 |
| Zakir2 | 2018-10-01 | 9.00 | 2018-10-02 | 9.00 |
| Zakir3 | 2018-10-01 | 7.00 | 2018-10-02 | 7.00 |

From this table I want the result like..

| Name | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-02 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Zakir1 | 8.00 | 8.00 |
| Zakir2 | 9.00 | 9.00 |
| Zakir3 | 7.00 | 7.00 |

What is postgreSQL Query ?

Comment: That's not good even for reporting.. Database work not like spreadsheet..

Comment: @dwir182 It's right but i need this query because i want to join two query with matching D1,...,D31

Comment: is that your table design? now october so have 31 days and 31 column days? so 1 table 1 month with 28/29/30/31 column days?

Comment: hard to do when you have design like that.. consider to restructure your db..

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, you don't even need a `crosstab()` query for this. Just:

```
SELECT name, AttendHour1 AS "2018-10-01", AttendHour2 AS "2018-10-02"
FROM   time;
```

If your desire is to assign column *names* dynamically from column *values*: that's not possible. SQL does not allow dynamic column names. You need a two-step workflow:

1. Create the query string dynamically.

To generate above query:

```
SELECT format('SELECT name, AttendHour1 AS %I, AttendHour2 AS %I FROM time'
             , date1, date2)
FROM   time
LIMIT  1;
```

2. Execute the query.

Comment: here "2018-10-01" and "2018-10-02" both are column value and this value also unknown @Erwin Brandstetter

Comment: @ZakirHossain: Guessing what you might be getting at, I added some pointers.