# How to show all dates from a certain date range in horizontal row?

Tags: sql, time-series, row, postgresql-9.1, generate-series

I have database table in PostgreSQL named as `t1` like:

| Name | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Oct-18 | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-05 |

I want the result for the date range like:

| Oct-18 | 2018-10-01 | 2018-10-02 | 2018-10-03 | 2018-10-04 | 2018-10-05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

with the help of `generate_series()` I can do it "vertically", but how to get the result in a single row?

Comment: Re asking same question will not help [Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077581/how-to-show-all-date-from-a-certain-month-by-horizontally)

Comment: sorry dear it's little different. @dwir182

Comment: Use crosstab.. To do pivot,, If you already do generate_series() make the result set as pivot..

Comment: then what will be the exact crosstab query. I do fail. @dwir182

Comment: @dwir182: `crosstab()` does not work for a dynamic number of result columns. There are limited workarounds ... I added some links below.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter ah great.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`. But SQL does not allow a dynamic number of result columns. So you must wrap your result in a string, array or document type to make it work.
Example with an ARRAY constructor in a `LATERAL` subquery - in Postgres 10 or later:

```
SELECT t1.name, d.date_arr::date[]
FROM   t1
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(SELECT generate_series(t1.startdate::timestamp
                                     , t1.enddate::timestamp
                                     , interval '1 day'))
   ) d(date_arr) ON true;
```

Why (preferably) Postgres 10 or later?

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

Why the cast to `timestamp`?

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

Why `LEFT JOIN .. ON true`?

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Though `LEFT JOIN` is not necessary in this particular case (could be `CROSS JOIN`) because the ARRAY constructor always returns a row.

#### Postgres 9.1

`LATERAL` requires Postgres 9.3 or later. You can substitute with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT name
     , ARRAY(SELECT generate_series(startdate::timestamp
                                  , enddate::timestamp
                                  , interval '1 day')::date)
FROM   t1;
```

Even works with pg 8.4:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=217d261457a0a33812ff6b9264e21576)*

But consider upgrading to a current version.

#### `crosstab()`?

`crosstab()` cannot overcome the static nature of SQL, either. There are limited workarounds with prepared row types ...

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)
- [Dynamically generate columns for crosstab in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879672/dynamically-generate-columns-for-crosstab-in-postgresql/12887645#12887645)
- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: #ErwinBrandstetter, sorry i found syntax error after the ARRAY key word, i am using postgreSQL 9.1. is this query valid for this version ?

Comment: @ZakirHossain: `LATERAL` requires Postgres 9.3 or later. I added an alternative.

Comment: @ Erwin Brandstetter: output fine but i need array's value's column position. That mean i get the value "{2018-10-01,2018-10-02,2018-10-03,2018-10-04,2018-10-05}" but i need each value's column position like | 2018-10-01 | |2018-10-02|  |2018-10-03|  |2018-10-04|   |2018-10-05 | because i want to compare this column with another column value.

Comment: *Updated to fix misleading typo:* Postgres does not allow a dynamic number of result columns. You can only achieve this with a two-step workflow, like I wrote under your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53094035/939860 (And it's impossible on principle for multiple rows to disagree on the number of columns.)