# Postgres join on json array values

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

I have a table `users` as follows:

```
|  id  |        name         |
|  1   |  Marvin Hargraves   |
|  2   |  Lincoln Clayton    |
|  3   |  Frank Pearce       |
```

And a table `posts` where I got json column with attributes:

```
|  id   |        attributes       | content |
|  11   | {"user_ids":["1", "2"]} |  "xyz"  |
|  12   | {"user_ids":["1", "3"]} |  "xyz"  |
```

Id's in the array reference the user from `users` table.
I need to display user names instead of IDs like:

```
    |  id   |                 users                   |
as an array
    |  11   | ["Marvin Hargraves", "Lincoln Clayton"] |
or string
    |  12   | "Marvin Hargraves, Frank Pearce"        |
```

I'm using PostgreSQL version 10.
I tried this query:

```sql
SELECT p.id, 
  (SELECT array_agg(array[u.name])
   FROM post AS p
   JOIN user u ON u.id = ANY(p.attributes->'user_ids')
   GROUP BY p.id) AS users
FROM post p
```

But I got the following error:

> ```
> ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
> ```

Comment: json or jsonb? Do you just query id and users, or more columns in your real query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) in a `LATERAL` subquery:

```sql
SELECT p.id, j.users
FROM   post p
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT u.name
      FROM   jsonb_array_elements_text(p.attributes->'user_ids') WITH ORDINALITY j(user_id, ord)
      JOIN   users u ON u.id = j.user_id::int
      ORDER  BY j.ord
      ) AS users
   ) j
;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6b8cbebefe739f331d74df2bce8ec8fe)*

Note that `null` values in the array are ignored.

The `CROSS JOIN` never eliminates rows in this case because the ARRAY constructor always returns a row, even when the JSON array is empty or NULL.

Related:

- [How to show all dates from a certain date range in horizontal row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093777/how-to-show-all-dates-from-a-certain-date-range-in-horizontal-row/53093860#53093860)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159717/3684)
- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use jsonb_array_elements_text to unpack the jsonb array, join to users, and then aggregate it back together:

```
SELECT p.id, array_agg(name ORDER BY i) as users
FROM post p
-- Use WITH ORDINALITY to preserve the order of the original array
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(p.attributes->'user_ids') WITH ORDINALITY AS j(user_id, i)
JOIN users ON users.id = j.user_id::int
GROUP BY p.id
;
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m5FG5VpqsMJjAaw3xVuGZo/0).